# The use of the verb "comprise"

Tags: verb-usage

1. > Singapore comprises one main island and several offshore islands.
2. > Singapore is comprised of one main island and several offshore islands.

Are these two sentences grammatically correct and which one better?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the sentences are equally acceptable. As for which is better, that would be your choice of style.

Some argue that "*BE* comprised of" is incorrect usage, but there's really no reason to treat it differently from other transitive verbs.

> ## [Usage note](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comprise)
>
> *Comprise* has had an interesting history of sense development. In addition to its original senses, dating from the 15th century, “to include” and “to consist of ” ( The United States of America comprises 50 states), comprise has had since the late 18th century the meaning “to form or constitute” ( Fifty states comprise the United States of America). Since the late 19th century it has also been used in passive constructions with a sense synonymous with that of one of its original meanings “to consist of, be composed of ”: The United States of America is comprised of 50 states.These later uses are often criticized, but they occur with increasing frequency even in formal speech and writing.

For the record, [comprises](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=43701945) has a frequency of 1204 and [is comprised of](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=43701913) has a frequency of 358, of course part of it due to overzealous copy-editing.

Also, the [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comprises%2Cis+comprised+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomprises%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20comprised%20of%3B%2Cc0) agrees with what's already said in dict.reference. The existence of "is comprised of" is certainly notable and **not** negligible:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences are correct grammatically.

Comprise is a transitive verb. You can also use it in the passive voice in the form of "be comprised of". You can use either Comprise or comprised of; both are usually used in formal English.

You can use " consist of" instead of comprise/be comprised of as "consist of" is  more common and used in both formal and informal English.